# Regarding No module named MDAnlaysis in Sublime text 3

Tags: python, module

I have installed the MDAnalysis package which is an object-oriented Python library to analyze trajectories from molecular dynamics (MD) simulations.
but if i open the .py file in sublime text which has code written in python with headers/starting line as:-

import MDAnalysis as MDAnalysis
u = mda.Universe('md.tpr' , 'md.trr')..

I am getting error as :-

ImportError: No module named MDAnalysis

Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1

shell_cmd: python -u "/home/dhn/Documents/Codes/MDAnalysis/MDA1.py"

dir: /home/dhn/Documents/Codes/MDAnalysis

how can i solve this issue..??

how can i insert the module MDAnalysis(in my case) in sublime text 3 such tht the library will be installed and i can run the code successfully...

Comment: Please clarify how you installed the package

Comment: I installed it from the mdanalysis page manual... by typing the following commands in UBUNTU 14.04 terminal                                                  conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install mdanalysis                                                                                          conda update mdanalysis                                                                                         conda install MDAnalysisTests

Comment: So you did `pip install  MDAnalysis`?

Comment: yes i tried with tht too..but i am getting error... so i tried with conda installation..                                                                                                        nw if i type pip3 install --upgrade MDAnalysis i am getting Requirement already up-to-date: MDAnalysis in ........Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib>=1.5.1->MDAnalysis)

Comment: Are you using Python 3? If you are it should be `pip3 install MDAnalysis`

Comment: yes im using python 3 and in terminal also i typed the above commands and nw it is showing Requirements already up-to date.........                                           Requirement already up-to-date: decorator>=3.4.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from networkx>=1.0->MDAnalysis)